# How to handle dynamic schema of JSON objects in Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, schema

I have a kafka stream to consume which contains some information in JSON form.

I need to convert that json data into Pandas dataframe to feed it further into a data warehouse.

The problem is that the json data structure keeps on changing depending upon the event types.

Example:

The first event comes in with the structure as:

```
{
    "organization": "nation1",
    "job_id": 1,
    "job_name": "job1",
    "state": {
        "started": "no"
    },
    "timetamp": 1570357814930
}
```

Then another event comes in with this structure:

```
{
    "organization": "nation1",
    "job_id": 1,
    "job_name": "job1",
    "state": {
        "started": "yes",
        "attended": "yes"
    },
    "timetamp": 1570357814988
}
```

Notice the change in **state** object above.

Assuming that the lowest level structure/hierarchy is not going to change, i.e.; the **state** object can have at-max the **started** and **attended** key-value pairs but not more. Although as can be seen in first event, the **state** object has only **started** in it.

How can I make sure that I get a pandas dataframe like below for such scenario. Keeping in mind that the actual json will have many such fields/maps which will have dynamic structure like this

[image]

Comment: Try [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@Chris A` suggested, I think it can be solved using `json_normalize`.
Try like these.

```py
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = '''
[{
    "organization": "nation1",
    "job_id": 1,
    "job_name": "job1",
    "state": {
        "started": "no"
    },
    "timetamp": 1570357814930
},
{
    "organization": "nation1",
    "job_id": 1,
    "job_name": "job1",
    "state": {
        "started": "yes",
        "attended": "yes"
    },
    "timetamp": 1570357814988
}]
'''

json_normalize(json.loads(data))
```

it gives you the below dataframe

```
    organization    job_id  job_name    timetamp    state.started   state.attended
0   nation1     1   job1    1570357814930   no  NaN
1   nation1     1   job1    1570357814988   yes     yes
```

#### Add columns which are not present

```
data = '''
{
    "organization": "nation1",
    "job_id": 1,
    "job_name": "job1",
    "state": {
        "started": "no"
    },
    "timetamp": 1570357814930
}
'''
df = json_normalize(json.loads(data))
expected_columns = {'state.started', 'state.attended'}
for column in expected_columns - set(df.columns):
    df[column] = 'null'
df
```

Comment: This would work if the complete structure (all the columns) are available in any one of the json messages within 1 json file. for example event-2 in my case contains all the columns that should come in . But since I am fetching it using kafka, I will be getting these events independently. So I would get the first json and I have to read it into pandas, then the second one will come in after some time.

one option I could think of is to define all the columns that may come in, and then dump the incoming messages into that pandas DF ?

Comment: In that case, you can add columns which are not present in current df with default value `null` . I'll update my answer with that change.